# How to make ipython do not leave edit mode after press ctrl-enter

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

In ipython 2.1.0, we have edit mode and command mode. After entering the cell, ctrl-enter would evaluate the cell in place and focus on current cell, but leave the edit mode. So if I need to continue to edit the cell, there is an extra 'Enter' to press. 
Is there a way to make the default behavior stay the Edit Mode?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the IPython javascript API to modify shortcuts.

If you use the `IPython.keyboard_manager.edit_shortcuts.add_shortcut` command you can change the ctrl-enter shortcut to not change focus.

```
%%javascript

IPython.keyboard_manager.edit_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-enter', {
    help : "run cell and keep focus", //This is optional
    handler : function (event) {
        IPython.notebook.execute_cell();
        IPython.notebook.edit_mode();
        return false;
    }}
);
```

The `edit_shortcuts` can be replaced with `command_shortcuts` if you need to edit the shortcuts for command mode.

Likewise, `add_shortcut` can be replaced with `remove_shortcut` should you need to delete an existing shortcut.

Comment: Just tried it does work as I needed, just found there is a replicable "bug" behavior: If I turn pdb on by using `%pdb`, and run the cell using ctrl-Enter, then if there is Error, code execution will break and on the bottom of the output, a pdb debug bar will appear.If I forgot to quit the bar, the ipython frontend will hide(delete?) the output and try to execute the cell, but then the kernel is waiting on the PDB bar thus is frozen. More annoying is that it seems it also stops responding to interrupt kernel, so I have to restart, and this is usually at the cost running notebook again.

Comment: Also I compared ipython own behavior, if I didn't quit pdb bar and press ctrl-Enter, it will close pdb first and then you need to press next time ctrl-Enter to run the cell.